# Batch convert tab files to shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, convert, batch, tab

I've seen several questions asking how to convert .tab files to .shp files in QGIS, MapInfo etc, which is what I'd like to do. However I have several files and I was wondering if there was a tool available to do a batch convert of several files in a folder from .tab to .shp?

I've had a look around but not found an answer, apologies if this is a duplicate, if so feel free to just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your question is a partial duplicate to this question and answer pair: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68389/batch-convert-xy-to-shapefile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ogr2ogr convert all shapefiles in a directory](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory just the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If would use ogr2ogr.

Did you google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=bacth+shapefiles+to+tab&oq=bacth+shapefiles+to+tab&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl

like

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/nt_3glZZClg

[Using ogr2ogr to convert all shapefiles in directory?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14494/Mapinfo-Tab-to-ESRI-Shapefile-Converter