# Drawing a marker on a shapefile with the given latitude and longitude?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, coordinates, markers

I am using shapefiles to draw a custom map. They were created successfully with the help of ArcGIS Desktop.

Now I need to draw a marker on shapefile based on an existing tuple of `lat, lng`.

How can I do that?

I am not using any map service for this.

I need to place a marker on given `lat, lng`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS SE. Your question is a bit unclear, do you want to add a label showing the latitude and longitude or do you need to add a point at a specific coordinate? Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks.

EDIT: Nevermind, thanks @Taras

Comment: Hello @TeddyTedTed, i need to add a point at specific lat/lng coordinate in shape file.

Comment: Have you seen these articles: [Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm), [Adding XY data to ArcGIS](https://blogs.otago.ac.nz/si-geology/2015/04/16/adding-xy-data-to-arcgis/) or [How to Add XY Coordinates to a File in ArcGIS](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-add-xy-coordinates-to-a-file-in-arcgis/).

Comment: You had a tag for QGIS but made no mention of it in your question body so I've removed it. If you want to ask a similar question about QGIS then please do that in a separate question

Comment: @Taras can i do this without using the tool, because i have to integrate it with my system?

Comment: Yes, you can. With the help of ArcPy, see [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) or [XY Table To Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm). There is also a thread on GIS SE: [Batch convert xy to shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68389/batch-convert-xy-to-shapefile)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to save your data as a .csv and open it into your map using the Add Data button, right-click the table and select the Display XY data option. Depending on where your data came from the projection will vary but remember that WGS84 is the standard for handheld GPS and Google Maps among other things.